# Logging errors on Windows 2003 Server using the EventLog class

Tags: c#, windows, error-handling

I've tried logging errors in my application, using the `EventLog` class.. But the Event Viewer on Windows 2003 Server is very limited as far as displaying the stuff I log.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
if (!EventLog.SourceExists("TestApp.exe"))
{
    EventLog.CreateEventSource("TestApp.exe", "TestApp");
}

EventLog.WriteEntry("TestApp.exe", Exception.Message);
```

The entry shows up in the Event Viewer, but I can't seem to find the the exception-message anywhere in the interface.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is the Event Viewer in Windows 2003 Server just crap? Are there any alternatives, beyond dumping errors to a text-file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up logging errors to a text-file, since the Event Viewer in Windows 2003 is far too simple to display the data I want to log.

Answer (score 0):

Two options are [Systems.Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx) and [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html)

Both can be configured to log to the file system, database, emails, eventlog, console, etc...

Log4net is my preferred option as I usually use NHibernate for data access.

Answer (score 0):

Event properties should include needed information. You just have to double click event in the Event Viewer on 2003.